# Our macro with changing "," into "." - not working for dots

Tags: replace, selection

I tried to register simply macro. It should delete the spaces in data visible in columns A:D and also should replace "," with ".".

Data in columns A:D is copied and pasted from outlook e-mail.
Below code works for spaces, but doesn't replace "," with ".".

what is interesting, when I manually write "," or when I add "," into already pasted data somewhere in the columns, the macro works just fine. From some reason, it doesn't recognize "," in pasted values. Is it something wrong with formatting?

The Macro was registered in the most simpliest way, it means I clicked "register macro" and then used "CTRL+F" and changed " " with "" and "," with ".".

Thank in advance for help

```
Sub Makro2()
'
' Makro2 Makro
'
' Klawisz skrótu: Ctrl+h
'
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        
    Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Range("C9").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, do you have maybe any ideas, why this macro won't change the "," into "." ?